# Top round transparent window

Tags: qt, window, qml, transparency

I'm currently learning QML and I want to create a top round transparent window.

I've build something that looks like that, but it seems wrong for multiple reason.

Here's my code:

```
Window {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 70
    height: 70

    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground

    Rectangle {

        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: parent.width / 2.0

        color: "black"

        MouseArea {
            property point clickPos: "1,1"

            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent

            onPressed: {
                clickPos  = Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                var delta = Qt.point(mouse.x-clickPos.x, mouse.y-clickPos.y)
                app.x += delta.x;
                app.y += delta.y;
            }

            onDoubleClicked: app.close()
        }
    }
}
```

using these flags in the main :

```
QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);

QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

The main problem is that the background is not transparent.

[image: Seems fine]

[image: Not fine]

I think it is because the 'round' rectangle is fully painted !?

I've tried multiple flags (Qt.Tool, Qt.Transparent, ...) but none works.

I was wondering if I started well to do what I want (I think I don't) and what is the best way to do it.

I've seen the clipping property for the qml item but I also see there's performance issues. I don't know if it's a good idea to use that property.

I'm running on Qt 5.10 and Win7 using MSVC as compiler.

Thank you

EDIT: Adding transparent background color to the window

[image: BackgroundColorWindow]

Comment: I can't say hello, don't know why... So I say it here. Hello guys

Comment: Did you try setting the window color to transparent?

Comment: Yeah, I did. But then, the square fill the entire window and is not round anymore

Comment: The window is never round. You can at best create an illusion that it is. Set the `color` for `Window`, not for the rectangle...

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I use a Rectangle inside of a Window. I wanted to make the window transparent and the rectangle with a certain color. But when I give the window a color, the Rectangle behaviour is weird and it seems that he fill completely the parent Window (Rectangle is no more round then).

Comment: OMG, just add `color: "#00000000"` to your `Window` from your first snipped and it works exactly like you want it to.

Comment: No, it's not... That's the first thing I tried and it didn't work. Updating my post

Comment: `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` is **not** a window flag, but a widget attribute. Setting it as a flag has no effect. Have you tried using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setFormat

Comment: @Felix just because it is not relevant to window doesn't mean it won't have any effect. Just not a desired effect, as it is still just a numerical value and it is still being set, because Qt doesn't have any safeguards against setting an unrelated flag.

Comment: Right, I removed the wrong flag to be sure.

Comment: The flag was wrong but it wasn't the problem, it did work for me as desired even with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an answer, just so I can post an image to prove to you that all you need is to set the color:

```
Window {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 70
    height: 70

    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    color: "#00000000"

    Rectangle {

        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: parent.width / 2.0

        color: ma.pressed ? "red" : "black"

        MouseArea {
            id: ma
            property point clickPos: "1,1"

            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent

            onPressed: {
                clickPos  = Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                var delta = Qt.point(mouse.x-clickPos.x, mouse.y-clickPos.y)
                app.x += delta.x;
                app.y += delta.y;
            }

            onDoubleClicked: app.close()
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

I didn't use any of the flags you are setting from C++, maybe `setDefaultAlphaBuffer()` is breaking it for you.

Comment: Copy/pasting your code didn't gave me the same output as you. I still have the black rectangle around my red cricle. That's very weird, I tried to remove both of my C++ settings, but it's still the same. Can you post your main.cpp???

Comment: It is the standard auto-generated main.cpp for a new blank project. Maybe your project is not rebuilding. Try clean all / run qmake / rebuild all.

Comment: Done. Nothing changed. I have the auto generated main for QtQuickApplication (the empty one). Is it the same as you? Here's a link of what I have: [Output](https://imgur.com/a/ClU0Z6I)

Comment: Well, in that case it might be some bug. I am using Qt 5.11 on windows 7 with mingw, but I've used transparent windows with previous versions of Qt without a problem. And I doubt the compiler would make a difference. So it might be an external issue, say some incompatibility with the graphics card drivers.

Comment: Alright, that's weird. I'm gonna do some test at home to see if there is any changes. Thx

Comment: Did you try testing that in a new blank un-built project? Qt has the nasty habit of not properly rebuilding code upon changes, it has had stale cached data related bugs before as well, so putting the code in a new project outta avoid any such issues. If the issue persists, you might want to report it at bugreports.qt.io

Comment: Just tried. Nothing better, still the same black rectangle.

Comment: Well, it is definitely a bug then. You should report it, together with your graphics card and driver information.

Comment: I've tested the code on some testing QML project and that work just like @dtech shows

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

Searching more deeply on the net and thx to @dtech, I found this [article](https://forum.qt.io/topic/78170/qt-transparent-window-graphic-card)

It was the exact same problem as me. But without @dtech, I would never have thought about the graphic card problem, which led me to this solution.

It seems that you need to have the **aero** mode enable on windows in order to be able to use transparency on Qt.

I activated the aero mode and then retried the given solution (the one of @dtech), it works very nice.

EDIT: It's a well known "bug" on [Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60130?jql=text%20~%20%22aero%20transparency%22)

Now that I have the solution, it seems obvious but I didn't think about it before.

Thx everyone